# How to build OpenSSL 1.0 DLLs with less secure TLS protocol versions disabled?

Tags: c, ssl, dll, openssl, tls1.2

I have a closed-source Windows server application that provides an FTPS service. It has been mandated that the service should refuse TLS connections using protocol versions lower than 1.2.

The application uses 32-bit versions of the DLLs `libssl32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` for its OpenSSL implementation, so my idea is to compile a custom version of these DLLs that disallows the use of TLS 1.0 and 1.1.

After much searching, I found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/919528) that describes config flags such as `no-tls1` and `no-tls1-method` to respectively disable the negotiation and implementation of the given protocol version. This, however, turned out to be a dead end since those flags are only available in OpenSSL versions 1.1 and later.

I was able to compile DLLs for OpenSSL 1.1.1, but they were incompatible with the application. Compiling OpenSSL 1.0.2 produced compatible DLLs, but I was unable to achieve the desired behavior using flags available in 1.0.2. That version does have a `no-tls1` flag, but its behavior is different from the flag in 1.1.x, and using it had no effect on TLS protocol negotiation.

At this point, it seems like my only option is to modify the source code for OpenSSL 1.0.2u to prevent use of the undesirable TLS versions. Being unfamiliar with the code base, I am posting this in the hope that someone could help by describing what would need to be modified to achieve my goal. I am open to considering alternative solutions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish my goal by modifying the `ssl23_get_client_hello()` function in `ssl\s23_srvr.c` to check the requested version and throw an `SSL_R_UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL` error if it's less than TLS 1.2.